# InternalHttpClient.getParams() with UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, exception, httpclient

I wrote a JAVA crawler and try to use `proxy` and ignore any `https certification`.

But it does not work with

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>       (at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.getParams)

I searched solutions that mostly say my `HttpClient`'s version is old, but I update to the latest version from apache website, this exception still happened.

Followed code is my crawler code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
                }
        };
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
        LayeredConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(ctx);
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory).build();            
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8888,"http");
        client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.javaworld.com.tw/jute/post/view?bid=29&id=312144");
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        String entity = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "utf-8");
        System.out.println(entity);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was because the method is deprecated and not available in latest versions.

I tried the below code and it worked for me

```
        public static HttpClient createClient() {
        try {
            SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
            builder.useProtocol("TLSv1.2");
            builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    builder.build());

            HttpClientBuilder hcBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
            HttpHost httpProxy = new HttpHost(bundle.getString("PROXY_HOST"), Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("PROXY_PORT")));
            DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(httpProxy);
            hcBuilder.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);

            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = hcBuilder
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

            return httpclient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Excuse me, what are the 'builder' of new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    builder.build()) and 'bundle' of bundle.getString("PROXY_HOST") mean?

Comment: I have updated the code to include the full method. This should help.